# How to uninstall an invalid global NPM package?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I list my globally installed packages, I get output like this:

```
home$ npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/local/lib
├── n@2.1.4
├── npm@2.14.12
├── npm-check-updates@2.8.9
├── @acme/somelib@1.1.16 -> /Users/me/projects/somelib (acme-somelib) invalid
└── yarn@0.21.3
```

The "somelib" package above is reported as invalid. I'd like to remove the "somelib" package to be sure that it's not contributing to some other problem, and generally, just to keep things clean. But the uninstall command fails for me:

```
home$ npm uninstall -g @acme/somelib
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "@acme/somelib"
```

I tried also to reinstall ( `npm install -g @acme/somelib` ) and then do an uninstall. In this case, the install creates a new and separate package that doesn't influence the invalid package. So that doesn't do anything to fix the problem.

How do I get rid of the invalid package?

Comment: `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/@acme/somelib@1.1.16` ? I don't think npm does any other bookkeeping for global packages.

Comment: That fixed it, @Felix Kling. Feel free to add an answer, if you like, and I'll accept it. I learned also that the path of the package did not match the name in package.json, which seems to have caused the invalidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the package directory from the command line. E.g. `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/@acme/somelib@1.1.16`.

Restated comment answer from @FelixKling for the sake of following the Q&A pattern. Thanks, Felix.